# Integrating Flyway into an existing database

Tags: flyway

We have not used Flyway from the beginning of our project. We are at an advanced state of development. An expert review has suggested to use Flyway in our project.

The problem is that we have moved part of our services (microservices) into another testing environment as well.

What is the best way to properly implement Flyway? The requirements are:

1. In Development environment, no need to alter the schema which is already existing. But all new scripts should be done using Flyway.
2. In Testing environment, no need to alter the schema which is already existing. But what is not available in testing environment should be created automatically using Flyway when we do migrate project from Dev to test.
3. When we do migration to a totally new envrionment (UAT, Production etc) the entire schema should be created automatically using Flyway.

From the documentation, what I understood is:

1. Take a backup of the development schema (both DDL and DML) as SQL script files, give a file name like V1_0_1__initial.sql.
2. Clean the development database using "flyway clean".
3. Baseline the Development database "flyway baseline -baselineversion=1.0.0"
4. Now, execute "flyway migrate" which will apply the SQL script file V1_0_1__initial.sql.
5. Any new scripts should be written with higher version numbers (like V2_0_1__account_table.sql)

Is  this the correct way or is there any better way to do this?

The problem is that I have a test database where we have different set of data (Data in Dev and test are different and I would like to keep the data as it is in both the environments). If so, is it good to separate the DDL and DML in different script files when we take it from the Dev environment and apply them separately in each environment? The DML can be added manually as required; but bit confused if I am doing the right thing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, there are actually two questions here. Data management and Flyway management.

In terms of data management, yes, that should be a separate thing. Data grows and grows. Trying to manage data, beyond simple lookup tables, from source control quickly becomes very problematic. Not to mention that you want different data in different environments. This also makes automating deployments much more difficult (branching would be your friend if you insist on going this route, one branch for each data set, then deploy appropriately).

You can implement Flyway on an existing project, yes. The key is establishing the baseline. You don't have to do all the steps you outlined above. Let's say you have an existing database. You have to get the script that defines that database. That single script should include all appropriate DDL (and, if you want, DML). Name it following the Flyway standards. Something like V1.0__Baseline.sql.

With that in place, all you must do is run:

```
flyway baseline
```

That will establish your existing code base as the start point. From there, you just have to create scripts following the naming standard: V1.1xxx V2.0xxx V53000.1xxx. And run

```
flyway migrate
```

To deploy appropriate changes.

The only caveat to this is that, as the documentation states, you must ensure that all your databases match this V1.0 that you're creating and marking as the baseline. Any deviation will cause errors as you introduce new changes and migrate them into place. As long as you've got matching baseline points, you should be able to proceed with different data in different environments with no issues.

Comment: Thank you Grant for the answer. I'm confused about one thing: When I migrate to a new empty database, why do I have to baseline? Flyway can start from beginning (maybe version zero as the baseline which is the default). For existing database, I understand this. I'll accept the answer after your reply.

Comment: If you're going to a brand new database, you don't need to baseline. The 'migrate' command will deploy the database you have. Your baseline, in a blank database, is the database. Heck, I've used Flyway deployments where the first script, V1, is the CREATE DATABASE command in the script. So you really don't need to baseline in a blank database.

Comment: Thanks Grant! Understood 

Comment: Creating a baseline is about two things. First, you're starting work in an existing database, so you need to establish that start point. Second, you've had to make adjustments out of band, manual scripts or what not, and as a way to reset so you can move forward with Flyway again, you establish a new baseline. Hope that helps.

Comment: Not a problem. And sorry I hadn't voted the question up. Fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

This is my [how-to instruction on integration flyway with prod DB](https://delicious-snipe-938.notion.site/How-to-integrate-Flyway-with-existing-MySQL-DB-in-Prod-PostgreSQL-is-similar-1eabafa8a0e844e88205c2f32513bbbe)

1. Use `MySQLWorkbench` to connect to prod DB.
2. Click menu Sever > Data Export
3. Select the DB and tables, choose `Dump Structure Only`
4. Selection option `Export to selft-contained file` and change the name of exported file (eg: `schema-backup.sql`)
5. Repeat step 1 to step 4 but at step 3 choose `Dump Data Only` and change the name of exported file (eg: `data-backup.sql`)
6. Use `MySQLWorkbench` to create a new local DB.
7. Run `schema-backup.sql` and `data-backup.sql` to the newly created local DB to make it as same state as prod DB.
8. Install `flyway` if it’s not installed.
9. Clone this repo and follow the `README.md` file https://github.com/haintwork/flyway-db-migration-starter-kit, but stop before step 7 in `README.md` file.
10. Comment the `migrate` command in `migrate-db-local.sh` script, uncomment the `baseline` command.
11. Copy content of `schema-backup.sql` and replace to `V1__Init_DB.sql` file.
12. Run step 7 of `README.md` file and check the local DB has new table `flyway_schema_history` and column success value 1.
13. Create new sql file `V1_0_1__Init_test.sql` in `sql` folder of the code with content

    ```sql
    CREATE TABLE test (
        id serial PRIMARY KEY,
        text VARCHAR ( 50 ) UNIQUE NOT NULL
    );
    ```
14. Open script file `migrate-db-local.sh` and comment `baseline` command and uncomment `migrate` command
15. Run `/bin/bash/migrate-db-local.sh` and check if new `test` table is created in local DB, if yes then it’s fine now.
16. Clone file `migrate-db-local.sh` to `migrate-db-prod.sh` and update prod db info in the script.
17. Uncomment the `baseline` and comment `migrate`
18. Run `/bin/bash/migrate-db-prod.sh` and check if table `flyway_schema_history` is created in prod db.
19. Comment `baseline` and uncomment `migrate` and run `/bin/bash/migrate-db-prod.sh` again and check if `test` table is created in prod DB. If yes then we are done.
20. Now using the starter kit to write migration db script and write CI/CD to auto integrating the DB.